# LoadError: no such file to load -- rack/handler/glassfish

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, glassfish

I have Successfully installed glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java, but when I run Rails Server using the command `Jruby -S rails server glassfish`. The output is follows:

**f:\Program Files\BitNami JRubyStack\jruby\depot>Jruby -S rails s glassfish**

> Exiting
>    LoadError: no such file to load -- rack/handler/glassfish
>        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
>    try_require at F:/Program Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gem
>   s/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:63
>   ......

Any questions? Should I run Tomcat or Glassfish first?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run `rails server` anymore, you just run glassfish.

```
f:\Program Files\BitNami JRubyStack\jruby\depot>glassfish
```

That will start up glassfish for your depot project.  Check out [their documentation](http://glassfishgem.rubyforge.org/) for a little more information about this.  That being said I think the glassfish project is kind of dying.  From what I understand Oracle has killed glassfish (http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/04/glassfish-gem-alternatives-jruby).  I would take a look at using [Trinidad](http://thinkincode.net/trinidad/) or [Torquebox](http://torquebox.org/) as alternatives.